# How to resolve the following C2220 error?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am getting the following error while building a project. Even though I am setting the 
property "treat warning as errors" to "NO" I am getting this one:

```
error C2220: warning treated as error - no object file is created.
```

Can any one Help me Resolving This One? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Perhaps you have "treat as errors" off on the project level, but on for this specific cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for C2220](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksk5k0ta(VS.80).aspx) suggests compiling at a lower warning level.  It also shows that the warning treated as error option is implemented as a compiler flag: /WX.  So you could search your .vcproj file for that text and manually remove it from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to add an header. Just where you get the first warning and see in what header file is defined.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I got "error C2220: warning treated as error - no object file is created." in below code.
Once I changed **datatype** of total to **int** , the error was resolved.

```
int colNum=0;
unsigned int total=123;
for (colNum=0;colNum<total;colNum++) {
```

Comment: Great!  This resolve my problem. I tried to assign the return value of a function which is boolean to a bool variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4146)
```

Set this at the file level instead of changing the project setting.